# Average distance of some vectors from a reference vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distance, vectorization

I have a n×k matrix and I want to get average distance of n vectors from a reference 1×k vector. I can do it using `norm(v(i, :) - test)` inside a `for` loop, but is there any minimal solution to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use PDIST2 function:

```
mean(pdist2(X,test))
```

or if you dont have access to Statistics toolbox:

```
mean(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, test).^2,2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) that computes distances between two sets of observations.

```
d = pdist2( v, test );
mean( d )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all distances using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun)

```
d = bsxfun(@minus, v, test);
d = sqrt( sum( d.^2, 2 ) ); % distance of each vector from test
mean( d )
```

Comment: why do you post two answers rather than appending this alternative to your original, as @Amro did?

Comment: @TryHard because these are two different answers. you may like one of them and not the other.

Comment: Ok, but I hope you don't miss the humor in this. union(your two answers) == answer(Amro)

Comment: @TryHard I also noticed that mean(my posting times) == postTime(Amro). I actually thought of `pdist2` after I already posted `bsxfun`, and while I wrote my second post Amro posted his. I can see people prefer the `pdist2` solution to the `bsxfun` one.

Comment: haha, yes the timeline goes like this: `Shai_bsxfun -> Amro_pdist_bsxfun -> Shai_pdist`, all within less than a minute between each other :)